# system of quadratic equations python

Tags: python

I got a system of quadratic equations:

```
(6.3205-x)**2+(-0.0347-y)**2-(1.4869)**2 = 0
(8.3769-x)**2+(-0.6242-y)**2-(0.8459)**2 = 0
```

I am looking for a smart way of solving it using Python. Any recommendations what library I should go with?

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic on SO. See [ask] and the other content in the [help].

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect

Comment: You have to create/implement the algorithm yourself in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest SymPy (a symbolic math library). It's powerful, but it can take a lot of head-scratching to figure out how to make it work.

```
import sympy

x, y = sympy.symbols("x y", real=True)

eq1 = sympy.Eq((6.3205 - x)**2 + (-0.0347 - y)**2, 1.4869**2)
eq2 = sympy.Eq((8.3769 - x)**2 + (-0.6242 - y)**2, 0.8459**2)

sympy.solve([eq1, eq2])
```

which gives

```
[
    {y: -0.852406950510941, x: 7.56236430542394},
    {y: 0.000885037011691020, x: 7.80697412192102}
]
```